# Firebase AuthUI for Android - skip Twitter OAuth page if app is approved

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth, firebaseui

I've integrated Firebase AuthUI into my Android application.  When using Twitter auth (and possible other social auth providers), I experience that even if I've authorized my application for use with Twitter authentication (my Twitter privacy setting show my app is already approved), I still get prompted with the Twitter OAuth app authorization page every time I try to log in with Twitter.

Normally in a web-based application you would skip that page and automatically logged in and immeduately sent to the OAuth redirect link.

Is there any way to make AuthUI behave this way in an Android app - meaning skipping app authorization if it has already been completed once?

The screen I am talking about is attached:

[image: Twitter OAuth page]

Comment: Firebase Auth UI is open source, so you can make it do whatever you want, within the bound of what the Twitter integration offers. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes that would be a last resort.  I'm just wondering if there are existing options to automatically progress past this screen like a web application typically does.  You may be correct that i will look to patch the source if no other options present themselves